# Implement tensor operation with mini batches instead of Matrix multiplication in forward pass

Tags: algorithm-request, tensor, forward-pass

The forward pass in neural network can be written as g(Wx+b). W is the weights Matrix, x is the input vector and b is bias, and g the non linearity, the activation function. However x can have more than one dimension if the input is a image it becomes 2D. Also if we use minibatches we stack images and becomes 3D.

I think that while using images in 2D for x would require W to becomes 3D, I think that stacking images for batches do not require W to become 4D since W would be the same for all the slices. A useless memory  usage increase.

Is there any general purpose algorithm that scales to N dimensions? So I can do M minibatches with N dimensions in one go?

Looking for the algorithm for instructional purposes. Something programming-like, I already tried abstract tensor stuff and I'm not even sure it is what I need

Comment: AxBxC matmul CxZ = AxBxZ… so having additional dimensions don’t really matter

Comment: Can you show an algorithm for that? I cannot find it